# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. On IIS

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel

I am having this error when I am trying to import my excel file. I already downloaded the  2007 Office System Driver but still no luck.

It works when I am building it in my VS 2015. Runs in x86. But when I try to run it in my IIS I get the error. Already tried changing my Enable 32-Bit Applications to True but still no joy,

Anyone knows how to do solve this?

```
OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False");
```

Comment: I think installin [this] (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) is the solution

Comment: @OguzOzgul worked like a charm. Thanks